# Serializable vs Data Contract vs Nothing at all in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I will use the Starter Example given when you create a WCF Service

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember] 
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

When I use DataContract everything is ok.

When I use Serializable, the actual variables, whether private or public are visualable to the host and not the Properties.  If I use NonSerialized it does hide the variable but it doesn't get passed either.  I get that, and I think I get why the properties are not passed because there is nothing to serialize?  Is that correct?

```
[Serializable]
public class CompositeType
{
    [NonSerialized]
    bool boolValue = true;
    [NonSerialized]
    string stringValue = "Hello ";


    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }


    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

If I do not supply any attributes, the class gets returned as expected, and this I do not understand?

I am tasked with taking existing business objects and working with them through WCF?  It looks like my best option is to leave them alone instead of adding a DataContract attribute.  Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[DataContract]` attribute is optional.

Why ever use it, then?  It lets you control what and how your data is serialized -- for example, which properties are to be included & excluded.

If you can get by without it, that is fine, but you may soon find that you need greater control over what and how data gets sent over the wire.

Comment: Great answer! However, Mike, you shouldn't try to get by without DataContract as it is WCF-service-oriented. ;)